# Reputation change text cut in the middle in activity dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, activity-dropdown

Here's how the activity dropdown on SO looks for me:

[image]

Note that the top question (named [`How do I notify all forks of my code of a critical change?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13881712/57428)) has its title cut in the middle although it could have been shown in full here but the next item with rather long title is displayed almost completely.

This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Back when we added the dropdown `text-overflow: ellipsis;` wasn't as widely supported as it is today.  Starting with the next, build it'll properly truncate at the end via your modern browser rather than a hard 50 character limit.